# Unit testing Spring Boot application Service layer

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm a bit confused about the test capabilities and utilities provided by Spring Boot.

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-test` in my project and I'd like to unit test my services without the database connection

At the moment I'm using `@WebMvcTest` for contoller test suites and `@SpringBootTest` for all the other test classes.

But I read somewhere that `@SpringBootTest` is meant to be used only in integration tests...

Reading [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) I didn't understood what's the suggested approach for services. Should I only test them in integration with repos?

**UPDATE**

That's an excerpt of a test class for one of my services:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
internal class SignupServiceTest(
        @Autowired val signupService: SignupService
) {
    @MockkBean
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Test
    fun `should return exception if username already used`() {
        every { userRepository.findByUsername("registered-user") } returns fakeUser(username = "registered-user")

        assertThatThrownBy {
            signupService.createNewAccount(fakeSignupForm(username = "registered-user"))
        }.isExactlyInstanceOf(UsernameNotAvailableException::class.java)
    }

    // ... other tests

}
```

Comment: No, you should test individual service classes by mocking repo layer. Yes you should not use `@SpringbootTest` which will load whole application context, which is not needed for unit tests

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do (I'm using MockK for this), but the database connection is still required...

Comment: not necessary. Put the relevant code, may be its easier to suggest

Comment: @pvpkiran I added some code

Comment: instead of springboottest use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and instead of `@Autowired` and `@MockBean` use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`

Comment: @pvpkiran so, basically I should run service tests as if there was no spring boot at all, right?

Comment: yes, that would be my suggestion. Springboot provides utilities for integration tests, but nothing specific to unit tests. or you have to use some embedded database(For this springboot provides `@DataJpaTest` `@DataMongoTest`.....). We should not try to kill a fly with an axe. :) We shud only use the frameworks capabilites if it reduces or minimizes the complexity

Comment: @pvpkiran Thank you. I'd like to accept your suggestions as answer to my question. Would you create an  answer from your comments?

Comment: Done!!! Added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `@SpringBootTest` for unit tests is a bit of a overkill. Because this would boot up the whole application context.

To test individual (service) classes I would go with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and instead of `@Autowired` and `@MockBean` use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`(If you use constructor injection, you wouldn't have to use this. which would be the better option)

You could still use `@Autowired` with `@ContextConfiguration` and load specific classes(if there are not too many transitive dependencies)

If you do not want to use mocks, then you can use embedded databases and use `@DataMongoTest` or `@DataJpaTest` and use Springboot testing capabilities.

Keep it simple....

Comment: These are useful informations, could you provide doc references?

Answer (score 3):

You should favor implementing unit tests to test your business logic (tests running without Spring, plain JUnit tests) over integration tests (tests starting a Spring container, `@SpringBootTest`) as they are more lightweight and give you feedback a lot faster.

Quote from [Spring Boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-applications)

> One of the major advantages of dependency injection is that it should make your code easier to unit test. You can instantiate objects by using the new operator without even involving Spring. You can also use mock objects instead of real dependencies.
>
> Often, you need to move beyond unit testing and start integration testing (with a Spring ApplicationContext). It is useful to be able to perform integration testing without requiring deployment of your application or needing to connect to other infrastructure.

Comment: This. I use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)` for all Service unit tests, and mock all the dependencies. Works really well, and they run quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

try to mock the calls to database using mockito, or use h2 database for the tests

Answer (score 0):

I was previously using @SpringBootTest as well then realized it was also trying to connect to my database, which should not be needed since it's a simple service test and all dependencies are mocked. After a bit of research I found this solution works quite well. Also note now my spring properties were not being injected so I used @Spy to create a pojo property object with some test values.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

/**
 * This is the bean under test as it is not a mock
 */
@InjectMocks
private MyService myService;

@Mock
private OtherService otherService;

@Spy
private MyServiceProperties properties = mockProperties();

@BeforeEach
public void configureMocks() {
   given(this.otherService.getData(any())).willReturn(mockDataResponse());
}

@Test
void testMyServiceReport_Success() {
    myService.runReport();

//assert response as needed
    verify(otherService, times(1)).getData(any());
}
```

Also here is some help with the imports which can sometimes be confusing:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.times;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.verify;
```